# finding the second row of the matrix CD

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If C is the $2\times 3$ matrix 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0&2&1\\
1&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and D is a $3\times m$ matrix, then the second row of the matrix $CD$ is?

Comment: The very fact that $D$ is unknown (hence arbitrary) is a clue that the answer is probably very simple. Suggestion: Choose a specific $D$ and do the multiplication. See what happens.

Comment: @Timothy M Parker besides giving the raw text of your homework, what have **you** attempted ? Moreover, you have asked 3 questions within the last hour, all without any work. Don't you think it's time to breath a little and work by yourself ?

Comment: No answer. You look uninterested by exchanging about your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Sum of the first and third (last) row of $D$.